# How to set Transparent background in Xamarin forms

Tags: xml, xamarin.forms

I have a png image that i want to display in a bitmap but when running the app the background is displayed in black , i want to set the transparency to none is there a way to do it ? 
the effect that i want to achieve is to see the app logo appearing on the middle of  my phone's home screen

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the **BackgroundColor** of the **Image** to **Transparent**.

I hope this helps. :)

```
<Image Source = "your_image.png" BackgroundColor = "Transparent"/>
```